# Vuetify Navigation Drawer Starts Closed and Then Opens a Second Later

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have set up a Vuetify Navigation Drawer on NuxtJS using Vuex to handle the state of the drawer.  Everything works fine except for one problem -- namely, that when I load the page on a desktop, the drawer starts out closed and then a split second later opens up.  Here is a video of my doing a hard refresh to see what I am referring to:  https://www.loom.com/share/477eb0933b3840d2bf7a9b55aaa8e934

Here is my code:

```
//app-bar.vue
<template>
  <v-app-bar app color="indigo" dark>
    <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="mainDrawer = !mainDrawer" />
    <v-toolbar-title>Application</v-toolbar-title>
  </v-app-bar>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    mainDrawer: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.getters.getMainDrawer;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.dispatch("toggleMainDrawer", value);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

```
// nav-drawer.vue
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer v-model="mainDrawer" app>
    <v-list dense>
      ...LIST_ITEMS
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    mainDrawer: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.getters.getMainDrawer;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.dispatch("toggleMainDrawer", value);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

```
// index.js (vuex file)
import Vuex from "vuex";

const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      mainDrawer: null
    },
    getters: {
      getMainDrawer: state => state.mainDrawer
    },
    mutations: {
      toggleMainDrawer(state, value) {
        state.mainDrawer = value;
      }
    },
    actions: {
      toggleMainDrawer({ commit }, value) {
        commit("toggleMainDrawer", value);
      }
    }
  });
};

export default createStore;
```

Any idea why this is happening and what I can do to change it.  I should note, that when I run the page using Android Studio Emulator it works just fine.  It's only desktop that I have an issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I just came across this same issue. Any chance you found an answer?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and tried many ways to fix it.
The only way i have found so far is to use the navigation drawer prop called `disable-resize-watcher` .
Its default value is false, so when you reload the page for some reason the nav drawer opens up. Setting this prop's value to true will fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks! It was driving me nuts; for me this issue popped after an update..

Comment: I am facing the same issue and `disable-resize-watcher` is not work for me

Comment: adding `disable-resize-watcher` worked for me thanks

Comment: `disable-resize-watcher` not working

Answer (score 0):

Few things that you should look into to fix this:

- Are you using `v-app` as the root of your appliacation. According to [this](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application) doc, it is mandatory to do it.
- Do you really need `app` prop on your `v-navigation-bar` and `v-app-bar`. The documentation describes it's use:

  > Designates the component as part of the application layout. Used for dynamically adjusting content sizing. Components using this prop should reside outside of v-content component to function properly.